# $f(x)$ differentiable $\implies$ $f(x+v) = f(x) + f'(x)\cdot v + r(v)$. How to define mixed derivatives this way?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}^p$ be a twice differentiable application in the
>   open $U\subset \mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$. Define the mixed
>   derivatives
>
> $$\frac{\partial ^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}, \frac{\partial^2
>  f}{\partial y \partial x}$$
>
> and establish the relation between them.

IN multivariable calculus, a function $f$ is differentiable if when

$$f(x+v) = f(x) + f'(x)\cdot v + r(v)$$

we have $\lim r(v) = 0$

this $f'(x)$ is a linear transformation normally called the Jacobian. It's a matrix, and can be applied to a vector $v$. What about the partial derivatives? How to define them?

Comment: you need to differentiate twice

Comment: The partial derivatives can be used to [define](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) the Jacobian. Defining derivatives of matrices and vectors wrt matrices and vectors is the domain of [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus).